# How do I force Kubernetes to re-pull an image?

Tags: image, pull, kubernetes

I have the following replication controller in Kubernetes on GKE:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: myapp
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    app: myapp
    deployment: initial
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
        deployment: initial
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myapp
        image: myregistry.com/myapp:5c3dda6b
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: myregistry.com-registry-key
```

Now, if I say

```
kubectl rolling-update myapp --image=us.gcr.io/project-107012/myapp:5c3dda6b
```

the rolling update is performed, but no re-pull.  Why?

Comment: You should use different image when updating.

Comment: I gave a different image, just with the same tag.  If it is necessary to give a different tag, well, I see no point in the `imagePullPolicy` field.

Comment: Out of interest, why would you want to do this? The only reason I can think of is using `latest` but if you use `latest`, it always pulls anyway.

Comment: I want to use a specific tag, but its newest version.

Comment: @TorstenBronger I think this is a breaking change in Kubernetes/Docker theory. The idea that you could pull image:tag (other than latest) at two different times and get two different images would be problematic. A tag is akin to a version number. It would be better practice to always change the tag when the image changes.

Comment: It depends.  There is software with a very stable API but security updates.  Then, I want the latest version without having to say so explicitly.

Comment: I am running into this issue now. The reason I want to have the same tag is to make a distinction between my staging and production environments without creating separate projects. And I'm making sure that `cloudbuild.yaml` gets the branch name to create the image version. Is that bad practice?

Comment: @TorstenBronger Regarding using `latest`, dont do it. Latest will pull the, well, more recently image with the latest tag. What you want is a SemVer range. ~1.2.3 for example. this will pull images with tags between the range of >= 1.2.3 and < 1.3.0.  As long as the image vendor follows [SemVer](https://semver.org/) your know (and this is the important part) no backwards breaking change were added (on purpose) and that no new features were added (possible security concern).  Please, please never use `latest` in production systems.

Comment: The question if and when to use `latest` is a different story. There are circumstance where it makes sense.

Comment: You could alternatively delete the deployment with kubectl delete command and then reapply if this is development time activity

Comment: @TorstenBronger please mark question as answered if you are clear on answer.

Comment: But this question is marked answered for a long time already.

Comment: I wrote a script
```
#!/bin/bash
kubectl patch deployment $1 -p '{"spec": {"template": {"spec":{"containers":[{"name": "'$1'", "imagePullPolicy":"Always"}]}}}}'
sleep 30
kubectl rollout restart deployment $1
sleep 120
kubectl patch deployment $1 -p '{"spec": {"template": {"spec":{"containers":[{"name": "'$1'", "imagePullPolicy":"IfNotPresent"}]}}}}'

```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/smyth64/8a32bb02a7354220234425e5a03dcffa

I wrote a simple bash script, check it out :)

Answer (score 158, accepted):

One has to group `imagePullPolicy` inside the container data instead of inside the spec data.  However, I filed an [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/15609) about this because I find it odd.  Besides, there is no error message.

So, this spec snippet works:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: myapp
    image: myregistry.com/myapp:5c3dda6b
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
    imagePullPolicy: Always
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: myregistry.com-registry-key
```

Comment: `imagePullPolicy` (or tagging `:latest`) is good if you want to always pull, but doesn't solve the question of pulling on demande.

Comment: Yes, I want to *always* pull, as stated in the question.

Comment: Using `imagePullPolicy: Always` inside the container definition will have `kubernetes` fetch images tagged with `:latest` whenever a newer version of them is pushed to the registry?

Comment: @pkaramol No. `imagePullPolicy: Always` simply tells Kubernetes to always pull image from the registry. What image it will is configured by `image` attribute. If you configure it to `image: your-image:latest`, then it will always pull the `your-image` image with the `latest` tag.

Comment: I just had the same issue here with a cronjob. The "latest" tag was ignored and only setting the job spec to the always pull policy made k8s reload the image for the next execution (=container creation) something seems to be different between these two options, despite every documentation treating them as equal.

Comment: @RomanGruber so I have a similar issue for a cronjob, the POD (in completed status) apprently didn't take the last DOCKER image, will it take when the cronjob executes again? or do i need to recreate again? imagePullPolicy: Always

Comment: @viruskimera - I seem to not be notified about all comments... Anyhow, it worked on my end; when I set the plicy to "always", it did pull the image again upon next execution.

Comment: This is part of the solution. After this you need to trigger `kubectl rollout restart deploy <name>`

Answer (score 291):

Kubernetes will pull upon Pod creation if either (see [updating-images doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#updating-images)):

- Using images tagged `:latest`
- `imagePullPolicy: Always` is specified

This is great if you want to always pull. But what if you want to do it **on demand**: For example, if you want to use `some-public-image:latest` but only want to pull a newer version manually when you ask for it. You can currently:

- Set `imagePullPolicy` to `IfNotPresent` or `Never` and [*pre-pull*](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#pre-pulled-images): Pull manually images on each cluster node so the latest is cached, then do a `kubectl rolling-update` or similar to restart Pods (ugly easily broken hack!)
- *Temporarily* change `imagePullPolicy`, do a `kubectl apply`, restart the pod (e.g. `kubectl rolling-update`), revert `imagePullPolicy`, redo a `kubectl apply` (ugly!)
- *Pull and push* `some-public-image:latest` to your private repository and do a `kubectl rolling-update` (heavy!)

No good solution for on-demand pull. If that changes, please comment; I'll update this answer.

Comment: You say kubernetes will pull on Pod creation when using `:latest` - what about `patch`ing? does it also always pull the newest/latest image? Seems not to work for me :(

Comment: It depends if your patch forces the re-creation of a Pod or not. Most likely not, then it'll not pull again. You may kill the Pod manually, or tag with something unique and patch with that updated tag.

Comment: This is an answer to a different question.  I asked for *forcing* a re-pull.

Comment: This allowed me to force a new pull from GCR. I had a `:latest` tag which pointed at a new image, and the `kubectl rolling-update` worked to update the pods.

Comment: Thanks. Went for the Pull & Push approach. Automated as much of it as possible with bash scripts but agreed, it's heavy :)

Comment: setting both those optiions are not working and i experimented with it. kuberneltes never pull the new image , although its showing in logs that its pulling the image.

Comment: How about having for each environment a label like "prod", "stage", "test", leave the imagePullPolicy to "always" and push the label, whenever you want to deploy, to the image that shall be deployed?

Comment: Do this iff your image tag is latest else take caution of the tag. Example if your image tag  comes form your CI environment

Answer (score 121):

There is a comand to directly do that:

Create a new `kubectl rollout restart` command that does a rolling restart of a deployment.

The [pull request](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/76062) got merged. It is part of the version `1.15` ([changelog](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.15.md)) or higher.

Comment: Yes part of Issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/13488

Comment: Yes,this is the best way to trigger update in new kubernetes verion of 1.15.

Comment: No there isn't a command to directly do that. This only work with `imagePullPolicy: Always` set.

Comment: @spinkus together with `kubectl rollout restart deploy <name>`

Comment: Life saver of an answer!! Shocked it took me this long to sort this out. Thank you.

Comment: @melroy-van-den-berg This is easy and perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 45):

My hack during development is to change my Deployment manifest to add the latest tag and always pull like so

```
image: etoews/my-image:latest
imagePullPolicy: Always
```

Then I delete the pod manually

```
kubectl delete pod my-app-3498980157-2zxhd
```

Because it's a Deployment, Kubernetes will automatically recreate the pod and pull the latest image.

Comment: I like taking advantage of the "desired state" premises of the "deployment" object... thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: It's worth noting that strategy is viable only if failures in the service and downtime are tolerable. For development it seems reasonable, but I would never carry this strategy over for a production deploy.

Comment: Edit the deployment, changing the imagePullPolicy to always and deleting the pod was enough for me, as Everett suggested. This is a development environment though. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/

Comment: The "Always" imagePullPolicy is the default for tags named "latest" or no tag. Therefore you don't need to specify it in this example

Answer (score 33):

A [popular workaround](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/27081#issuecomment-238078103) is to patch the deployment with a dummy annotation (or label):

```
kubectl patch deployment <name> -p \
  "{\"spec\":{\"template\":{\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{\"date\":\"`date +'%s'`\"}}}}}"
```

Assuming your deployment [meets these requirements](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#updating-images), this will cause K8s to pull any new image and redeploy.

Comment: Yes, I use an annotation for this.

Comment: what annotation?

Comment: Another sophisticated solution would be a combination of both ie. adding an annotation and setting `ImagePullPolicy` as *Always*.  annotations like `deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "v-someversion"` and `kubernetes.io/change-cause: the reason` can be quite helpful and heads towards immutable deployments.

Answer (score 18):

Now, the command `kubectl rollout restart deploy YOUR-DEPLOYMENT` combined with a `imagePullPolicy: Always` policy will allow you to restart all your pods with a latest version of your image.

Answer (score 17):

1. Specify strategy as:

```
  strategy: 
    type: Recreate
    rollingUpdate: null
```

2. Make sure you have different annotation for each deployment. Helm does it like:

```
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: AppName
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: ReleaseName
      annotations:
        rollme: {{ randAlphaNum 5 | quote }}
```

3. Specify image pull policy - Always

```
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: Always
```

Comment: Warning: changing the annotation value leads to the pod recreation even if the docker image has not been changed!

Answer (score 10):

```
# Linux

kubectl patch deployment <name> -p "{\"spec\":{\"template\":{\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{\"date\":\"`date +'%s'`\"}}}}}"

# windows

kubectl patch deployment <name> -p (-join("{\""spec\"":{\""template\"":{\""metadata\"":{\""annotations\"":{\""date\"":\""" , $(Get-Date -Format o).replace(':','-').replace('+','_') , "\""}}}}}"))
```

Answer (score 10):

This answer aims to force an image pull in a situation where your node has already downloaded an image with the same name, therefore even though you push a new image to container registry, when you spin up some pods, your pod says "image already present".

For a case in Azure Container Registry (probably AWS and GCP also provides this):

1. You can look to your Azure Container Registry and by checking the manifest creation date you can identify what image is the most recent one.
2. Then, copy its digest hash (which has a format of `sha256:xxx...xxx`).
3. You can scale down your current replica by running command below. Note that this will obviously stop your container and cause downtime.

```
kubectl scale --replicas=0 deployment <deployment-name> -n <namespace-name>
```

4. Then you can get the copy of the deployment.yaml by running:

```
kubectl get deployments.apps <deployment-name> -o yaml > deployment.yaml
```

5. Then change the line with image field from `<image-name>:<tag>` to `<image-name>@sha256:xxx...xxx`, save the file.
6. Now you can scale up your replicas again. New image will be pulled with its unique digest.

Note: It is assumed that, imagePullPolicy: Always field is present in the container.

Answer (score 10):

Having gone through all the other answers and not being satisfied, I found much better solution here: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/updating-apps

It works without using **latest** tag or **imagePullPolicy: Always**. It also works if you push new image to the same tag by specifying image sha256 digest.

Steps:

1. get image SHA256 from docker hub (see image below)
2. find your deployment using `kubectl get deployments`
3. `kubectl set image deployment/<your-deployment> <your_container_name>=<some/image>@sha256:<your sha>`
4. `kubectl scale deployment <your-deployment>--replicas=0`
5. `kubectl scale deployment <your-deployment>--replicas=original replicas count`

Note: Rollout might also work instead of scale but in my case we don't have enough hardware resources to create another instance and k8s gets stuck.

[image: docker hub sha256 location]

Comment: Small correction. In the second point, it should be <your_container_name> instead of <your-pod-name>

Comment: Setting replicas to 0 will cause a service outage. Is there a way to do this without taking the app down?

Answer (score 9):

Apparently now when you run a rolling-update with the `--image` argument the same as the existing container image, you must also specify an `--image-pull-policy`. The following command should force a pull of the image when it is the same as the container image:

`kubectl rolling-update myapp --image=us.gcr.io/project-107012/myapp:5c3dda6b --image-pull-policy Always`

Comment: Since Kubernetes 1.18 this feature is removed, as stated here: https://v1-18.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/notes/#kubectl

Answer (score 7):

The rolling update command, when given an image argument, [assumes that the image is different](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/staging/src/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/rollingupdate/rollingupdate.go) than what currently exists in the replication controller.

Comment: Does this mean the image tag (aka name) must be different?

Comment: Yes, the image name must be different if you pass the `--image` flag.

Comment: As my own answer says, it works also if the image name is the same.  It was simply that the imagePullPolicy was in the wrong place.  To my defence, the k8s 1.0 docs are erroneous in this aspect.

Comment: Gotta love when the docs are out of sync with the behavior. :/

Comment: The URL is outdated, use this one -> https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/kubectl/cmd/rollingupdate/rollingupdate.go (Not sure which line, though)

Comment: That url is outdated too.

Comment: kubectl has been moved into the "staging" part of the kubernetes repository (in preparation for moving to a separate repo in the future). The current link to the file is https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/staging/src/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/rollingupdate/rollingupdate.go

Answer (score 7):

You can define `imagePullPolicy: Always` in your deployment file.

Comment: works for dev environment, but for prod use rolligupdate strategy

Answer (score 5):

I have used kubectl rollout restart for my springboot api and it works.

```
kubectl rollout restart -f pod-staging.yml --namespace test
```

Yaml for the Deployment:

```
apiVersion: "apps/v1"
kind: "Deployment"
metadata:
    name: "my-api"
    labels:
      app: "my-api"
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: "my-api"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: "my-api"
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-api
          image: harbor.url.com/mycompany/my-api:staging
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8099
              protocol: TCP
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /actuator/health/liveness
              port: 8099
            initialDelaySeconds: 90
            periodSeconds: 10
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /actuator/health/readiness
              port: 8099
            initialDelaySeconds: 90
            periodSeconds: 5
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: "my-api-configmap"
          env:
            - name: "TOKEN_VALUE"
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: "my-api-secret"
                  key: "TOKEN_VALUE"
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "512Mi"
              cpu: "500m"
            limits:
              memory: "2048Mi"
              cpu: "1000m"
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: "my-ci-user"
```

Answer (score 4):

Defining `imagePullPolicy: Always` in the deployment would do.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

The Image pull policy will always actually help to pull the image every single time a new pod is created (this can be in any case like scaling the replicas, or pod dies and new pod is created)

But if you want to update the image of the current running pod, deployment is the best way. It leaves you flawless update without any problem (mainly when you have a persistent volume attached to the pod) :)

Answer (score 1):

The below solved my problem:

```
kubectl rollout restart
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to perform a direct image update on a specific pod, you can use `kubectl set image` also.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

either you have deleted all the pods manually to get it recreated with pulling the image again.

or

run this below command
kubectl rollout restart deployment/deployment_name
kubectl rollout restart deployment/nginx

this command should recreate all the pods.

for both scenarios imagepullPolicy should be set as Always.

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner solution based on invalidating Deployment hash by adding some new unique data, here: a timestamp-based environment variable (just like adding a "volatile" `ENV` to bust docker cache during image builds):

```
kubectl set env deployment/nginx REDEPLOY_TIME="$(date)"
```

or when using `oc Client Tools` under OCP/OKD:

```
oc set env dc/nginx REDEPLOY_TIME="$(date)"
```

It will trigger an automatic rolling re-deployment/re-pull even in older installations of k8s (not just in v1.15 or above, where `kubectl rollout restart` is the correct solution as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55914480/9962007)). In fact I verified this workaround even in the archaic Openshift 3.11 based on k8s 1.11 from mid-2018!

Note we need the usual prerequisites of `imagePullPolicy: Always` and a "rolling" container image tag such as `latest`.

Note: kudos and the original idea (using a YAML Deployment manifest file and `sed`) go back to [this comment](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/33664#issuecomment-292895327) in the rather long-running k8s issue devoted to this now thankfully gone opinionated choice made initially by k8s devs.

Answer (score 0):

I developed a lightweight Kubernetes tool [URunner](https://github.com/texano00/urunner) in order to **automatically** restart deployment resources while maintaining the same tag (es. `:latest`)

**URunner** can also be installed using **Helm** ([Artifacthub link](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/urunner/urunner))

It uses **Docker V2 API** standard in order to continuously check if a **Tag Digest** is changed and eventually perform the needed restarts.
So basically it is compatible with ALL available container registries (ex. AWS ECR, GCP, Harbor, DigitalOcean registry..)