# How can I make Kubernetes do an image pull every time a container restarts?

Tags: kubernetes

Kubernetes only seems to pull images when the pod is created, how can I make it re-pull the latest image when the container itself exits?

I'd want the same effect as `kubectl rollout restart deployment`, but when the container exits. For example, if the container is a shell script, and it does `exit 1`, Kubernetes should pull the latest image from registry before restarting.

My deployment has only 1 container if that matters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I force Kubernetes to re-pull an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112789/how-do-i-force-kubernetes-to-re-pull-an-image)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `imagePullPolicy`, read more over [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#updating-images).

Below is an example for your handy reference:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: pod-nginx-container-image-repull
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx-alpine-container-1
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - containerPort: 80
    imagePullPolicy: Always
```

---

**UPDATE 1:**

When you use `restartPolicy: Never` then it means that you are telling Kubernetes that I do not want my container to restart in case it crashes. So, you are experiencing that there is no image re-pull in case container "restart" because there was actually no container restart.

I had quickly copied an example from my workspace so you saw `restartPolicy: Never` in my example which was not meant for you, I have updated my above example to remove it. But I hope you have understood one more concept with it.

Another thing worth noting is that `restartPolicy` applies to all containers in a Pod while `imagePullPolicy` can set at container level in Pod.

Comment: With `restartPolicy: Never` the pod is stuck at the "Completed" status if the container dies and a new pod is never created. I already tried `imagePullPolicy: Always`, and it only works with `kubectl rollout restart deployment`, not if the container restarts.

Comment: @throwaway91234 I have updated my answer, please check and let me know in case of any question.