# standard_init_linux.go:219: exec user process caused: exec format error ECR + Quarkus

Tags: amazon-eks, quarkus, amazon-ecr, jib

Ok, I already know that there are many errors on SO, however I cannot find any that suits with my case.

**PREMISE:**

My environments is MacOS with M1.

I have an EKS cluster with *linux (amd64)* as OS architecture on AWS.

When trying to build and deploy my micro service with Quarkus, I set on application.properties:

```
quarkus.container-image.image=<my ECR repository>
quarkus.container-image.build=true
quarkus.container-image.push=true
quarkus.jib.platforms=linux/amd64
```

I'm using jib extension for building image.

Once the image is succesfully deployed on my ECR aws registry, I launch:

```
 kubectl apply -f target/kubernetes/kubernetes.yaml
```

then

```
 kubectl get po
```

I see

```
NAME                              READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
kube-cm-example-6ffd58655-rzzqh   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   8          16m
```

Then

```
kubectl logs kube-cm-example-6ffd58655-rzzqh
```

return the following output

```
standard_init_linux.go:219: exec user process caused: exec format error
```

I read on many sources it's a platform image issue, however using jib I set linux/amd64 which is  the same arch of the node.

I also tried to manually build a docker image specifying platform=linux/amd64 and then deploying to ECR, but nothing changes.

Comment: Could it be that the k8s cluster is not pulling new images? https://stackoverflow.com/a/35941366/1701388

Comment: I already tried to remove image from ecr and pushing new one, should be enough I think

Comment: No, deleting an image from ecr or pushing a new image does nothing. It may be that k8s is just not pulling an image from ecr.

Comment: You were right, setting imagePullPolicy: Always did the job. You may post a response for the vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the observations, it may be that your Kubernetes cluster is not pulling newly updated images from ECR when starting a pod. Unless some conditions are met, the default pull policy of k8s skips pulling images if they already exist. During development, you may consider making it always pull images. Take a look at this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35941366/1701388).