# How to kubectl re-apply deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I want to update my pod because there is a new image uploaded to docker registry with `latest` tag.

I am currently doing this:

```
kubectl delete -f deployment.yaml
kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
```

If I do:

```
kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
```

It says my deployment is unchanged.

**However, I want make my service alive even for a second. Isn't there a way I could do something like the following?**

```
kubectl re-apply -f deployment.yaml
```

Comment: `kubectl rollout restart deployment/xxx`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can just delete the POD once and restart the POD so it will change the image and pull new version from docker registry.

However, make sure `imagePullPolicy` set to **always** in your `deployment.yaml`

Or else you need to update one minor field into `deployment.yaml` and keep `imagePullPolicy` to **always** in that case apply will change the deployment.

**Example** :

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: test
    image: image:latest
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
    imagePullPolicy: Always
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: docker-secret
```

**Option 2**

```
kubectl rollout restart deployment/<deployment-name>
```

Read more at : [How do I force Kubernetes to re-pull an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112789/how-do-i-force-kubernetes-to-re-pull-an-image)

Answer (score 3):

The below command will do a rolling restart of your deployment even if the whole yaml is same and it says unchanged.

```
kubectl rollout restart -f deploy.yaml --selector=component=deploy
```

Here the trick is that we need to add additional label of `component: deploy` to the metadata of the deployment type so that it selectively only restarts the deployment only. This will add up as additional config update as well as one more command but will do the needful.